# ANCOVA with ordinal covariate?

Tags: repeated-measures, ordinal-data, ancova

My study looks at the effects of sex on performance in a psychological task. There are 3 variables: sex (m/f), plus 2 within-subjects factors (with 2 and 3 levels), so it's a 2x2x3 repeated-measures design. I found sex differences in the DV, but I also collected an ordinal measure from each subject (on a scale of 1-4, how often do you play video games?), and found that not only are there sex differences on the video game measure, but it also correlates with the DV.

I want to run a new test that takes into account video game use to see if the sex differences persist. Am I justified in using the traditional ANCOVA model with the ordinal measure as a covariate? Are any assumptions of ANCOVA violated if the covariate is not interval/ratio? Thanks.